# Сползли иконки сообществ в профилях

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Переходим в профиль пользователя

#### В сообществах видим следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### На странице активности в блоке учетных записей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### Смена профиля на странице профиля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### В верхнем меню в выпадающем списке с профилями

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### Комментарии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В общем они везде где  можно иконки сообществ посползали, часто в обрезанном виде и не соответствуют своему сообществу.

Возможно изменили спрайт, но не обновили стили (или наоборот).
В общем рассинхронизировались они.

Comment: У меня нормально показываются.

Comment: @Qwertiy сейчас и у меня нормально уже отображаются... Посмотрю потом было ли что-то на `meta.stackexchange` по этому поводу и отпишусь здесь

Comment: @Qwertiy да. Мне не показалось)) вот пост на "мета-мете" :https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381137/favicon-sprites-are-offset-in-site-list-dropdown-not-as-a-result-of-a-new-site

Comment: @Qwertiy , проставь потом, плиз, `статус-завершён`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогичный вопрос с репортом бага был опубликован на meta.stackexchange.com

[Favicon sprites are offset in site list dropdown, not as a result of a new site being created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381137/favicon-sprites-are-offset-in-site-list-dropdown-not-as-a-result-of-a-new-site)

После чего его приняли на рассмотрение и взяли в работу.

В `23:00` по МСК данный баг закрыли как `завершенный`
После чего на мете и русскоязычном сайте сообшества баг также перестал воспроизводиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]